# Ошибка при установке discord-components

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType
```

Пишет
`no module named 'discord_components'`

`pip install discord-components` не работает

`discord.py` обновлял